# R 3.1.1 installs ggplot2 successfully but cannot find file to load

Tags: r

I recently updated to Windows 8.1 and updated my R to 3.1.1 and after the updates, I had to reinstall anything that was added in the last week (`deSolve`,`FME` (and associated packages),`ggplot2`) because they gave this error when I input library("ggplot2"):

```
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Kerrigan/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/R/Rcpp.rdb': No such file or directory
```

`deSolve` and `FME` resolved after I reinstalled them but `ggplot2` still gives the error. Any ideas of how I can fix this? Thanks!

Edit: I did the install manually through R, though I also tried install.packages("ggplot2") and both said they installed properly.

Comment: Sounds like it didn't re-install all the dependencies. Did you do `update.packages()` or `install.packages()` in R to update? Sounds like Rcpp is still missing.

Comment: What do you mean by " ggplot2 still gives the error."? Rcpp is not in the Depends or Imports in the DESCRIPTION file with the ggplot2 package. (There is no package named "package".) We need the console transcript that produces this error!

Comment: Do you have [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed on your machine?

Comment: Do you have all the rights on your new machines?

Answer (score -2):

`library(ggplot2)` (remove the quotes)